# Separate on() function outside of createReducer() function in ngrx

Tags: ngrx

Is it possible to separate out the on() parameters from the createReducer() function.

For example, instead of this;

```
const yourInformationReducer = createReducer<IYourInformationState>(
    initYourInformationState,
    on(YourInformationStoreAction, (state, { payload }) => ({
        ...state,
        ...payload
    }))
);
```

Define a constant for the on() function;

```
const onYourInformationStoreAction = on<IYourInformationState>(
    YourInformationStoreAction,
    (
        state: IYourInformationState,
        { payload }: { payload: IYourInformationFormModel }
    ) => ({
        ...state,
        ...payload
    })
);
```

Then reference it in the createReducer;

```
const yourInformationReducer = createReducer<IYourInformationState>(
    initYourInformationState,
    onYourInformationStoreAction 
);
```

The problem I have is that when I set the type for the payload object in the separated out function, it gives a typescript error that I don't know how to deal with...

> Error:(16, 2) TS2345: Argument of type '(state: IYourInformationState,
>   { payload }: { payload: IYourInformationFormModel; }) => { name:
>   string; email: string; contactNumber: string; validityStatus:
>   ValidityStatus; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ActionCreator> |
>   OnReducer>]>'.   Type '(state:
>   IYourInformationState, { payload }: { payload:
>   IYourInformationFormModel; }) => { name: string; email: string;
>   contactNumber: string; validityStatus: ValidityStatus; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'ActionCreator>'.
>       Property 'type' is missing in type '(state: IYourInformationState, { payload }: { payload: IYourInformationFormModel; }) => { name:
>   string; email: string; contactNumber: string; validityStatus:
>   ValidityStatus; }' but required in type 'TypedAction'.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...

```
function onYourInformationInitAction() {
    return on(YourInformationInitAction, (state: IYourInformationState) => ({
        ...state
    }));
}

function onYourInformationStoreAction() {
    return on(
        YourInformationStoreAction,
        (state: IYourInformationState, { payload }) => ({
            ...state,
            ...payload
        })
    );
}

function onYourInformationValidityStatus() {
    return on(
        YourInformationUpdateValidityStatusAction,
        (state: IYourInformationState, { validityStatus }) => ({
            ...state,
            validityStatus
        })
    );
}

const yourInformationReducer = createReducer<IYourInformationState>(
    initYourInformationState,
    onYourInformationInitAction(),
    onYourInformationStoreAction(),
    onYourInformationValidityStatus()
);
```